# Found New Hardware Wizard keeps popping up

Tags: device-manager, windows-xp-embedded

I'm working on a PC running Windows Embedded Standard 2009 (similar to Windows XP, I think). The machine runs fine, but every time on reboot I get the Found New Hardware as in the image below:

[image]

I've tried all of the following:
(1) Finished the wizard and selected "Do not prompt to install this hardware again". Result: The Found New Wizard literally pops up again after about 2-3s!
(2) Cancelled the wizard, opened Control Panel > System > Hardware > Device Manager, and disabled the "PCI Simple Communications Controller".
(3) Cancelled the wizard, opened Control Panel > System > Hardware > Device Manager, and uninstalled the "PCI Simple Communications Controller".

The result of (1) is that the Found New Hardware Wizard literally pops up again after about 2-3s! The result of (2) or (3) is that on the next reboot...the darn Found New Hardware Wizard pops up again.

How do I stop Windows permanently from showing me anything to do with this device? I'm happy to dig around in the registry if that is what needs to be done.

Comment: Sorry it's not really clear but have you tried installing the latest driver for it.

Comment: This device usually is an onboard modem. You can find the drivers on the cd that came with your motherboard, or google for the motherboard and download them from the internet. Installing is the only way to get this resolved.

Comment: OK, issue resolved. The supplier of the PC had a backup clone of the machine before I started tinkering with it. I had accidentally uninstalled something called "Intel Management Engine Components". When I restarted from the clone, I left this alone and the issue has not re-appeared...so basically you were both right. It was a driver issue that could not be resolved any other way except by installing the drivers. Thanks!